# convert strings to numbers inside array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings:

> ["5:17", "8:22", "3:34", "5:23", "7:12", "7:24", "6:46", "4:45",
>   "4:40", "7:58", "11:51", "9:13", "5:50", "5:52", "5:49", "8:57",
>   "11:29", "3:07", "5:59", "3:31"]

How can I convert the strings to numbers?

Comment: This look like a time in string, can you please tell your expected output?

Comment: What number are you expecting for a string like "5:17" ?

Comment: time without string =)

Comment: This is totally unclear.

Comment: @JacklinTrio please tell what do you expect for "5:17" to be displayed as number?

Comment: What i see is, it's time - 5:17 means 5 hours and 17 minutes, now when displaying in number format, either you can display in minutes or in hours. What are you expecting here?

Comment: yeah Nitish Narang 5:17 i need

Comment: Great!!! Then it will be a string as you can't denote colon ':' as a number :)

Comment: As you can just use decimals

Comment: ooops sorry i need 317 seconds

Comment: Added an answer for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to convert string to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906931/not-able-to-convert-string-to-float) . I would argue that's an **exact** duplicate of the question. Quite strange.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use "[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)" as below

```
arr.map(d => {
    let [min, sec] = d.split(':')
    return +min * 60  + +sec
})
```