# Not able to convert string to float

Tags: javascript

I have a simple array of string but I am trying to convert it to array of decimal numbers like [5.22,8.22,rest of the numbers], but it is returning only array of whole numbers.

I am doing some rookie mistake which I am not able to notice

```js
let k = ["5:17", "8:22", "3:34", "5:23",
         "7:12", "7:24", "6:46", "4:45",
         "4:40", "7:58", "11:51", "9:13",
         "5:50", "5:52", "5:49", "8:57",
         "11:29", "3:07", "5:59", "3:31"];

let arrOfNum = k.reduce(function(acc, crr) {
  acc.push(parseFloat(crr))
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(arrOfNum)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `acc.push(parseFloat(crr))` to `acc.push(parseFloat(crr.replace(":",".")))`

JavaScript doesn't recognize colons as periods

Answer (score 1):

A float number doesn't follow this format `integer:decimal`,

```
it follows `integer.decimal`
                   ^
                   |
                   +--- the dot is the decimal separator in JS.
```

On the other hand, you don't need `reduce` for doing that, use the function `map` instead.

Likewise, I recommend you to use the object `Number`.  If you want, you can read a little about it [here](https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls)

```js
let k = ["5:17", "8:22", "3:34", "5:23","7:12", "7:24", "6:46", "4:45","4:40", "7:58", "11:51", "9:13","5:50", "5:52", "5:49", "8:57","11:29", "3:07", "5:59", "3:31"],
    arrOfNum = k.map((crr) => Number(crr.replace(':', '.')));

console.log(arrOfNum);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```